# Specify different filename for newplot.png in Plotly

Tags: plotly

I've found the Plotly config options here:

https://plot.ly/javascript/configuration-options

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js#L22-L86

However, for the "toImage" button (labelled "Download plot as a png") I cannot seem to configure what the image file is named. It is always called "newplot.png" but I would like to give it a different name. Is there any option for this?

I am using the JavaScript version of Plotly.

Comment: Possibly related to the OP's [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49126846/download-a-plotly-plot-as-a-jpeg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set this in the **Plotly** configuration using an undocumented variable:

```
  toImageButtonOptions
    // statically override options for toImage modebar button
    // allowed keys are format, filename, width, height, scale
    // see ../components/modebar/buttons.js
```

So for example you would put:

```
  toImageButtonOptions: {filename:"nameofyourfile"}
```